# Autogenerate number of inputfields

Tags: knockout.js

I want to auto generate number of fieldpairs when i select the number in a select list.

And each pair will bind values to an model which in turn is stored in an array.

I've created a [non-working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwe2B/3/). Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong?

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label><b>No of double fields to create</b>

    </label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <select data-bind="options: numberOfFields, value: selectedNumberOfFields, optionsCaption: 'Choose Number'"></select>
</div>

<br><br>

<div data-bind="visible: showFields()">
    <div data-bind="foreach: parameters">
        <label>Param:
            <input data-bind="value: param" />
        </label>
        <label>Operator:
            <input data-bind="value: operator" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwe2B/3/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I *think* you were looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwe2B/4/

What I did was get fix the typo in `Parameters` and then I got rid of the subscription for `selectedNumberOfFields` and instead used a `ko.computed` for `showFields`:

```
self.showFields = ko.computed(function() {
    var fields = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < self.selectedNumberOfFields(); i++) {
        fields.push(new Parameter());
    }
    return fields;
});
```

And your binding now looks like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: showFields">
    <div>
        <label>Param:
            <input data-bind="value: param" />
        </label>
        <label>Operator:
            <input data-bind="value: operator" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, that's exactly what i was trying to do. :) Thank you!

Comment: will self.showFields() contain all values that i wrote in the inputfields ?

Comment: @Henrik: Yes. Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwe2B/6/). I added a button that will log `self.showFields()` to the console. Note, however, that you didn't make the fields in `Parameters` observable, so knockout won't pick up changes automatically.